# How to connect to Selenoid browser container with VNC?

Tags: vnc, selenoid

I know what I can use Selenoid-UI to connect to running webdriver container using my browser. But is there any ability to connect to container using one of VNC clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible ways:

1) Launch browser VNC container as follows and connect with any VNC client using `vnc://localhost:4444` and password `selenoid`:

```
$ docker run -d --name browser -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 selenoid/vnc:firefox_58.0
```

2) Use Selenoid `/vnc/` API. Having some running session ID, e.g. `bd0415ac-3cbc-427d-b1e6-d142889a6afa` you can access a web-socket proxying VNC traffic like this:

```
ws://selenoid-host.example.com:4444/vnc/bd0415ac-3cbc-427d-b1e6-d142889a6afa
```

Getting VNC traffic from web-socket is a built-in feature of some web-based VNC clients, e.g. [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) used in Selenoid UI.

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest way to open VNC to selenoid:

`localhost:4444` - selenoid server

`2a398b1d73ca57e2559ad4ca785abae3` - your session id

https://novnc.com/noVNC/vnc.html?host=localhost&port=4444&path=vnc/2a398b1d73ca57e2559ad4ca785abae3&password=selenoid